# Rewrite SQL query to return rows for each dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, dataset

I have the following table for student's fee payments

```
[fee_id]         INT             
[user_id]        INT             
[payment]        DECIMAL (18, 2) 
[date]           DATETIME        
[fee_remaining]  DECIMAL (18, 2) 
[year]           INT             
[payment_method] NVARCHAR (50)
[fee_required]   DECIMAL (18, 2)
```

This is my current query to display the number of students who have either paid, yet to pay or have partially paid their fees for the year

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
   FROM fee_payments
   WHERE (fee_remaining = 0)
     AND (YEAR = @year)) AS Fully_Paid,

  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
   FROM fee_payments
   WHERE (fee_remaining = fee_required)
     AND (YEAR = @year)) AS Unpaid,

  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
   FROM fee_payments
   WHERE (fee_remaining > 0)
     AND (YEAR = @year)
     AND (fee_remaining <> fee_required)) AS Partially_Paid
FROM fee_payments AS fee_payments_1
```

This is my output

```
Fully_Paid | Unpaid | Partially_Paid
-------------------------------------
    8      |   1    |       5
```

Is it at all possible to have my output displayed as follows?

```
Status          | Total
----------------------------
Fully Paid      |   8
Unpaid          |   1
Partially Paid  |   5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `case` expression to assign the required status to each row and `group by` the calculated column.

```
select status, count(*) as total
from (
SELECT 
case when fee_remaining = 0 then 'fully_paid'
     when fee_remaining <> fee_required then 'partially_paid' 
     when fee_remaining = fee_required then 'unpaid' 
end as status
FROM fee_payments
WHERE YEAR = @year) t
group by status
```

Also note this assumes fee_remaining and fee_required are non null values. If they can be `null`, use `coalesce` to handle them when comparing.

Comment: i just modified it @Cᴏʀʏ

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So without *completely* restructuring your query into something more efficient like [kvp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36990923/74757), you could `UNION` each of the results instead of using them each as a sub-query:

```
SELECT 'Fully Paid' AS Status, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM fee_payments
WHERE (fee_remaining = 0) AND (YEAR = @year)
UNION
SELECT 'Unpaid', COUNT(*)
FROM fee_payments
WHERE (fee_remaining = fee_required) AND (YEAR = @year)
UNION 
SELECT 'Partially Paid', COUNT(*)
FROM fee_payments
WHERE (fee_remaining > 0) AND (YEAR = @year) AND (fee_remaining <> fee_required)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to have more than one row per year.  It seems like the last row would be the most informative, so I'm thinking something like this:

```
select sum(case when fee_remaining = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as FullyPaid,
       sum(case when fee_remaining < fee_required then 1 else 0 end) as PartiallyPaid,
       sum(case when fee_remaining = fee_required then 1 else 0 end) as Unpaid      
from (select fp.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from fee_payments fp
      where YEAR = @year
     ) fp
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'Fully Paid' as Status, COUNT(*) AS Total
   FROM fee_payments
   GROUP BY year
   WHERE fee_remaining = 0
     AND YEAR = @year
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Unpaid' as Status, COUNT(*) AS Total
   FROM fee_payments
   GROUP BY year
   WHERE fee_remaining = fee_required
     AND YEAR = @year
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Partially Paid' as Status, COUNT(*) AS Total
   FROM fee_payments
   GROUP BY year
   WHERE fee_remaining > 0
     AND YEAR = @year
     AND fee_remaining <> fee_required
```